# Is there more to uniform hypergraphs than to graphs "along with" their complete subgraphs?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hypergraphs

Given a uniform hypergraph on vertex set $V$, construct a simple graph on $V$ by joining $v, w\in V$ whenever they are contained in some hyperedge in $E$.

Conversely, given a graph on $V$ that admits a (not necessarily disjoint) edge decomposition into copies of $K_r$, set $h\in V^{(r)}$ to be a hyperedge whenever the $G$-induced subgraph on $h$ is complete.

As far as I see, these two constructs capture all information about one another and theorems about one can be translated to theorems about the other.

If this is true, what then is the additional value in considering the concept of a uniform hypergraph? Is there some intrinsic difference useful in a certain kind of problems or is this just because the hypergraph structure is more natural (if it is at all, seeing as we could equally well just consider a graph along with "generalized edges" given by its complete subgraphs...)?

Comment: wouldn't $K_n$ always induce $\binom{V}{k}$? while for example: steiner triple systems always induce $K_n$?

Comment: The Gaifman graph contains much of, but not all, the information in a hypergraph.  Consider a hypergraph with one three-vertex edge versus its Gaifman graph, considered as a hypergraph.

Comment: @TheKindCat Right. Same goes for finite projective planes etc. The graph described in the first paragraph of the question will lose most of the information in the hypergraph.